# file mass deletion

Tags: files, find

I would like to delete all the txt, xls,pdf files in a directory as well as its sub directories. I would like to save everything else.

```
find . -type f ! -iname '*.xml$,.png$,.jpeg$,.gif$,' -delete
```

that seemed to have done it, but it delete some other files that I need. How can I achieve that without deleting anything else?

Comment: `-iname` is a pattern, not regex and you negated it. You probably deleted all files from the current directory down.

Answer (score 4):

Do this instead:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.xml' -o -iname '*.png'\
       -o -iname '*.jpeg' -o -iname '*.gif' -delete
```

You could also use regular expressions:

```
find . -type f -iregex '.*\.\(xml\|png\|jpeg\|gif\)$' -delete
```

Comment: How do I delete anything that is over two years or older?

Comment: Use this option: `-mtime +730`. The time is specified in days. See the `find` manpage (`man find`) for more information. Some shells allow for the substitution of evaulated expressions, which can be useful in situations like these. `-mtime +$(( 365 * 2 ))`.

Comment: it did not like the -mtime option find: paths must precede expression: +730
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec]

Comment: Did you command look like `find . -mtime +730 -type f -iname '*.xml' -o -iname '*.png' -o -iname '*.jpeg' -o -iname '*.gif' -delete` or `find . -mtime +730`?

Comment: find . -mtime +730 -type f -iname '*.xml' -o -iname '*.png' -o -iname '*.jpeg' -o -iname '*.gif' -delete

Comment: Try `find . -type f -iname '*.xml' -o -iname '*.png' -o -iname '*.jpeg' -o -iname '*.gif' -mtime +730 -delete`

Comment: Note that the `-mtime` option works with file modification times. There isn't an option for first modification/original creation time.

Comment: The script ran fine, however it is not deleting everything that is older than 2 years. [root@virt1 payroll]# ls -l
total 212296
-rwxrwx---. 1 501 500  420896 Feb 12  2009 test wxx_payroll_310109.csv
-rwxrwx---. 1 501 500 2588810 Feb  1  2011 wpxxx_payroll_010211.txt
-rwxrwx---. 1 501 500 1027160 Jul  1  2009 wpxxx_010709.txt
-rwxrwx---. 1 501 500 2261140 Nov  1 17:44 wpxxxxxx.txt
-rwxrwx---. 1 501 500 1109392 Feb  2  2010 wpxxx.txt

Comment: I tried to delete all the docx, txt, pdf files Older than 2 years from /mnt/ftp and all its subdirectories. The problem is it removed some but did not delete others. As posted above on my last post.  it is still showing with files from 2009 which I want gone. 

cd /mnt/ftp
find . -type f -iname '*.docx' -o -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.pdf' -o -iname '*$

Comment: The file from 2009 has a `.csv` extension. Your command looks like it got cut off, but make sure you hav `-o -iname '*.csv'` in your command. Also run the command `date` and make sure your computer's date is set correctly.

Comment: The system has the right time. I didn't want to post all the files here because alot of them are confidential. I added the csv file there but most of the files from 2008,2009 and 2010 that I want to delete have not been deleted

Comment: Add the `-print` option to your command to see what files `find` is discovering. Could you please post the full command that you are using? Enclose it in backticks (``) so that it will look like `this`.

Comment: gtar -pczf ftpbackup.tar.gz /mnt/ftp/*/ --exclude={/mnt/ftp/*/_ben/images,/m$

cd /mnt/ftp
find . -type f -iname '*.docx' -o -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.pdf' -o -iname '*$

Comment: find . \( -type f -iname '*.docx' -o -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.pdf' -o -iname '*.xls' \) -mtime +730 -exec rm \{} \;

Comment: This is the command that finally worked.

find . -type f -iregex '.*\.\(docx\|xls\|txt\|cvs\)$' -mtime +730  -delete

Answer (score 2):

There are basically 4 ways in which to approach this problem using find.

#### Method #1 - using `-delete`

```
$ find . -type f -iname '*.xml' -o -iname '*.png'\
       -o -iname '*.jpeg' -o -iname '*.gif' -delete
```

As others have mentioned within this Q&A, this method is the fastest and least resource intensive. Quoting from the [find online docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Deleting-Files):

> 10.1.6 Using the `-delete' action
>
> ---
>
> The most efficient and secure method of solving this problem is to use
>   the `-delete' action:
>
> ```
>  find /var/tmp/stuff -mtime +90 -delete
> ```
>
> This alternative is more efficient than any of the `-exec' or`-execdir'
>   actions, since it entirely avoids the overhead of forking a new process
>   and using `exec' to run`/bin/rm'.  It is also normally more efficient
>   than `xargs' for the same reason.   The file deletion is performed from
>   the directory containing the entry to be deleted, so the`-delete' action
>   has the same security advantages as the `-execdir'
>   action has.
>
> The `-delete' action was introduced by the BSD family of operating systems.

**NOTE:** One thing to keep in mind with this approach, the use of `-delete` implies also the switch `-depth`. What does this mean? Here's an example of how `-delete` can burn you if you're not careful.

For example, say I have a subversion work directory where I want to clean up some files, but leave its .svn sub-directories intact. I might use the following command to accomplish this:

```
$ find . -not "(" -name .svn -type d -prune ")" -type f -print
./a.txt
```

But because `-delete` includes a `-depth` switch, the files that would actually be getting dealt with:

```
$ find . -not "(" -name .svn -type d -prune ")" -type f -print -depth
./.svn/all-wcprops
./.svn/entries
./.svn/format
./.svn/text-base/a.txt.svn-base
./a.txt
```

For this reason, when using `-delete`, care must be taken.

#### Method #2 - `-exec command {} +`

```
$ find . -type f -iname '*.xml' -o -iname '*.png'\
       -o -iname '*.jpeg' -o -iname '*.gif' -exec rm {} \+
```

Compared to the `-delete` method, this is most likely the next best option, in terms of performance & portability across Unixes. The `-exec ... {} +` notation works as follows:

**from find man page**

> This variant of the -exec action runs the specified command on the selected files, but the command line  is  built
>   by  appending each selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the command will be much less
>   than the number of matched files.  The command line is built in much the same way that xargs  builds its command
>   lines.  Only one instance of `{}' is allowed within the command.  The command is executed in the starting directory.

So in effect, this method works similar to `xargs`, but without having to jump through hoops of passing the output of a find through a pipe to `xargs`.

#### Method #3 - `xargs`

```
$ find . -type f -iname '*.xml' -o -iname '*.png'\
       -o -iname '*.jpeg' -o -iname '*.gif' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

The `find ... -print0` will build a list of files matching the specified criteria. This list is then passed through the pipe to `xargs`. The `-print0` switch puts an ASCII NUL character as a separator between each result from find. The `-0` switch on `xargs` makes it assume that the files being passed in are seperated by ASCII NUL characters.

Compared to methods #1 & #2, this one will have similar performance to #2, however the `-print0` switch is not universally supported across all Unixes.

#### Method #4 - `-exec command {} \;`

```
$ find . -type f -iname '*.xml' -o -iname '*.png'\
       -o -iname '*.jpeg' -o -iname '*.gif' | exec rm -f {} \;
```

Compared to the first 3 methods, this is the least performant. It literally calls the `rm` command for each individual file that the `find` command finds.

#### Additional considerations around security

One thing that might not be that obvious when using any of the above methods is that some of the methods are more secure than the others. You're probably saying to yourself, ... security? .. what? Here's an example.

Assume your root and you run the following command:

```
$ find /var/tmp/somedir -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Unbeknownst to you, someone has maliciously created a link to the `/etc` directory under `/var/tmp/somedir`. When the above command runs, the `/etc` directory will also be deleted. This issue exists with any of the methods for deleting files, except for the `-delete` option (method #1).

#### tl;dr;

The fastest and most secure way to delete files with the help of find is to use `-delete`. Using `xargs -0` can be similar in performance, but it is not as secure. The `-delete` action is not completely portable. The most efficient portable alternative is `-exec ... +`, but this is insecure and isn't supported by versions of GNU findutils prior to 4.2.12.

#### References

- [Deleting lots of files with find - Debian Administrators Blog](http://www.debian-administration.org/users/Steve/weblog/176)
- [Find Users Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html)
- [Efficiency of find exec vs. xargs](http://blog.endpoint.com/2010/07/efficiency-of-find-exec-vs-find-xargs.html)
- [Deleting Files with find](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Deleting-Files.html)

Comment: sters/FSA': Directory not empty tried with find -mtime +720 -delete on the directory sters/FSA': Directory not empty

Comment: Not sure what you tried there, can you update your question with the command you tried to run and the error messages?

Comment: Here is the command that I typed, it is deleting the txt, pdf and all the files mentioned. However, I still get files that dating back from 2008 or so. 

cd /mnt/ftp
find . -type f -iname '*.docx' -o -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.pdf' -o -iname '*$

Comment: Here's an upvote to balance things out. I enjoyed reading the article you linked, by the way.

Comment: `find` doesn't call the `rm` utility when you use `-delete`, it does the deletion by itself, so your recommendation to call `xargs` for efficiency is bogus (and even a little counterproductive). On top of that, **do not call `find … | xargs somecommand`** as `xargs` expects its input quoted in a format that `find` does not produce. Use `find … -print0 | xargs -0 somecommand` or just forget about `xargs` and use `find … -exec somecommand {} +` which has the same grouping effect. @EvanTeitelman Reserve your upvotes for answers that are helpful.

Comment: @Gilles, thanks for the constructive feedback. I've updated my answer so that it's now, hopefully, more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is an slight inaccuracy into [slm answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73346/file-mass-deletion/73358#73358).

**NOTE & Disclamer** : this have to be a comment to [slm answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73346/file-mass-deletion/73358#73358) but righ now I can't do comments yet.

The example "someone has maliciously created a link " given into **Additional considerations around security** is not totally accurate both about Unix hard links and for Unix soft links.

To understand the difference between the two please see [Hard link and Symbolic links in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808394/hard-link-and-symbolic-links-in-unix) or google it up.

For soft links (the most used type anyways) both `GNU find` and `BDS find` **does not** follow simbolic links unless is used a a specific `-L` flag to force symbolic link following.  [See `man find`]

So this example is likely to not be a prolem, unless you **force** `find` to follow soft links using the `-L` flag. This is the dangerous choice, anyways.

For hard links, `find` will follow the link to **another file** but please note that hard linking to a **another directory** "will probably fail " as see into `man ln` for GNU `ln` :

```
   -d, -F, --directory
          allow the superuser to attempt to hard link directories (note: will probably
          fail due to system restrictions, even for the superuser)
```

So it is probably impossible to create the hard link to a directory in the first place and `find` will have nothing to follow.

Note that some BDS `ln` implementation does not have a `-d` option at all.

Comment: With `-exec rm`, there's still a race condition as one can replace directory in `/var/tmp` in between the time `find` lists it and `rm` starts and calls the `unlink` system call. The (non-standard) `-delete` option solves that by using `fchdir` and `unlinkat` making sure find deletes what it thinks it deletes.